# Separate radio button for each group of possible answers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, radio-button

I am iterating through a list of questions and answers. For each question, I need a separate radio button that the user can select from that group of answers. The code below supplies one radio button for ALL of the answers, not for each set of answers.

```
<ol>
<% for question in @survey.questions %>
<li><%= question.content %></li>
<ul>
<% question.answers.each do |answer| %>

<%= radio_button_tag(:answer, answer.content ) %>
<%= label_tag(:answer_tag, answer.content ) %>
<% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
</ol>
```

Is it possible to do what I want to do?

Comment: Can you please add your model relation to your question? Thanks

Comment: Also your HTML is a bit funny. second batch of <li> is missing :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your question isn't terribly clear, but for one group of radio buttons per question, name the radio buttons with something unique to the question. The radio button's name is the first argument of `radio_button_tag`. E.g. `<%= radio_button_tag("answers_#{question.id}", answer.content) %>`.